# Android: Gallery View has been deprecated?

Tags: android, gallery, swipe, photo

I have been using the gallery control to show the photos and having problem when swiping the photo. I need to swipe all the way to change photo otherwise it will bounce back to the previous photo.

After checking up on the internet, I heard the gallery has been deprecated. What is the next control which can do the same as gallery control?

Comment: How about [Coverflow](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)?

Comment: Now ViewPager Available instead of GalleryView.

Comment: use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead

Comment: Then use View Flipper....

Comment: Thanks I just checked the View Flipper. It may be the one i should try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use a [`Gridview`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) to show images
- Combine `gridview` with [`View pager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to view selected images

[Here is a Tutorial from androidhive to get you started](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)