# How to display images in galleryview from the server using lazyloading

Tags: android, server, lazy-loading, galleryview

I have galleryview. I want to display images in galleryview by getting images from the server using lazy loading. How can I do this?

Comment: Please check these relevant links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447395/how-to-display-images-from-web-in-gallery-view-in-android
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112986/android-gallery-view-has-been-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

you  can also use the open resource Universal Image Loader.UIL aims to provide a powerful, flexible and highly customizable instrument for image loading, caching and displaying. It provides a lot of configuration options and good control over the image loading and caching process.